# Does every complex polynomial of degree not equal to 1 have a fixed point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $P$ is a complex polynomial of degree not equal to 1. Is it the case that $P$ has a fixed point?

Comment: Hint: $P-x$ is a non-constant complex polynomial so has at least one complex root.

Comment: @PeterForeman Wow, that's a lot smarter than what I was writing up ... oops.

Comment: @DonThousand I'm wondering what you wrote now.

Comment: @PeterForeman I was doing some stuff with Brouwer's Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f=P(x)-x$ and use the fundamental theorem of algebra, the degree being greater than one by condition $f=P(x)-x$  not constant.

Comment: This is exactly what @PeterForeman commented. I would let him post this as an answer, unless you have some more original context to add.

Comment: I was just writing this as the same idea came in the comments.

Comment: Didn´t want to start anew.